# SQL query which includes COUNT(*) in it's SELECT `clause` confuses me

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a newbie in SQL, trying to find my way through.

I have the following diagram:
[image]

and I'm being requested to

> "Produce a list of number of items from each product which was ordered
> in June 2004. Assume there's a function MONTH() and YEAR()"

The given solution is:

```
SELECT cat_num, COUNT(*)
FROM ord_rec AS O, include AS I
WHERE O.ord_num = I.ord_num AND
MONTH(O.ord_date) = 6 AND
YEAR(O.ord_date) = 2004
GROUP BY cat_num;
```

What I'm confused about is the **COUNT(*)**.  (specifically the asterisk within).

Does it COUNT all rows that are returned from the given query? So the asterisk refers to all of the returned ROWS? or am I far off?

Is it any different than having:

```
SELECT cat_num, COUNT(cat_num)
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would take the time to read the documentation and review [some tutorials](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/count.php). Aside, your example looks to have been around for over [30 years](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: That would mean: `O JOIN I` , instead of `WHERE O.ord_num = I.ord_num` ? Thanks for the tip:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The COUNT(*) function returns the number of rows in a dataset using the SELECT statement. The function counts rows with NULL, duplicate, and non-NULL values.

The COUNT(cat_num) function returns the number of rows that do not contain NULL values.

Consider an example:

| Block | Range |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1-10 |
| A | 10-1 |
| B | (NULL) |
| B | (NULL) |
| B | (NULL) |

For this data,using query:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*),
  COUNT(t.`Block`),
  COUNT(t.`Range`) 
FROM
  `test_table` t
```

You'll obtain results :

| count(*) | count(t.`Block`) | count(t.`Range`) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 5 | 2 |

I hope that clears your confusion.

Comment: Thanks! Short and helpful. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The COUNT(*) function returns the number of rows in a table in a query. It counts duplicate rows and rows that contain null values.

> Overall, you can use * or ALL or DISTINCT or some expression along
> with COUNT to COUNT the number of rows w.r.t. some condition or all of
> the rows, depending up on the arguments you are using along with
> COUNT() function.

[Possible parameters for COUNT()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuBKB.png)

When the * is used for COUNT(), all records ( rows ) are COUNTed if some content NULL but COUNT(column_name) does not COUNT a record if its field is NULL.

[Resources here](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/count-function.php#:%7E:text=The%20SQL%20COUNT()%20function,%5BALL%7CDISTINCT%5D%20expression%20).